# Force setup X-Frame-Options Django

Tags: django, x-frame-options

I tried different methods to setup **X-Frame-Options** to **'SAMEORIGIN'** in the *Django-server* responses, but it wasn't help:

1. I removed XFrame package from the middleware in *settings.py*.
2. I putted `X_FRAME_OPTIONS='SAMEORIGIN'` to *settings.py*
3. I added **'X-Frame-Options'** to response object with the same value in *my view* in which I wanted to use the `<iframe>`
4. I tried to add `@xframe_options_sameorigin` decorator to *my view*.
5. I also changed */etc/apache2/apache2.conf*, putted `Header always set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"` into it.

Then I tried to restart *apache2* service after all my actions but the result always the same:

```
X-Frame-Options setted as 'DENY'
```

My Django version is 2.2.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, some of this methods have worked. Update of browser page has not worked at first time, but after few minutes, it has worked. All done, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses), to set the same X-Frame-Options value for all responses in your site, put `'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'` to MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

Then set `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` in `settings.py`.

In Django 2 and below this is the default behavior: ([See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses))
`X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'`

Whereas in Django 3 and above is the opposite ([See docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses))
`X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'`

You want to set it to "SAMEORIGIN" to avoid these issues. Once you set it, make sure to restart your server.

[Learn more about X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).